# Formatting text inside the Excel spreadsheet cell

Tags: c#, excel

The code that I need to modify creates an excel spreadsheet and inserts search results in the cells. The logic finds the match and copies the entire row in the code. Then it replaces commas with `<comma>`, not sure why but that's not important. I need to highlight the specific word in this search result preferably bold and red. See the example below, the search parameter is COMPUTE and the result is the entire line of of code, which is as designed.

> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF STATISTICS_NORE**COMPUTE** = OFF IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON

I have some basic code that splits a 'context' variable into an string array and if a match is found it should format the word - however this is where my challenge lies.

I found tons of examples on how to format the entire cell or row, but not text within the cell. Is that not possible to do grammatically?

```
            string[] wordList = context.Split(' ');
            StringBuilder reassembleContext = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            regexPattern = new Regex(pattern.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            foreach (string word in wordList)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(word, pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    wordList[i] = "<b>" + word + "</b>"; // Clearly this does not work...
                }

                reassembleContext.Append(wordList[i]);
                reassembleContext.Append(" ");
                i++;
            }

            context = reassembleContext.ToString();
```

Comment: I know nothing about programming in `c#` for Excel, but in Excel itself, you can format text within the cell provided that the cell contents is a text string and not the result of a formula.  In VBA, you would use the characters property to determine which characters to format differently.

Comment: is this Interop.Excel, or OpenXML, or something else .. ?

Comment: It's Interop.Excel but that can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to put the HTML in the Clipboard, and paste it:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("<html>a<b>b</b>c");
    worksheet.Range["A1"].PasteSpecial();
```

Another is to use the cell's [`.Characters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.characters.aspx) property to set the formatting:

```
    worksheet.Range["A1"].Characters[38, 7].Font.Bold = true;
```